# Allowing VNC to control computer under 10.14 (Mojave)

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, mojave

I've seen some topics asking for help (others offering it) re: apps asking for permission to use accesibility functions with regards to VNC in Mojave. RealVNC has a page describing the issue and a fix for their client. I use iTeleport, which works with macOS' own screen sharing. The connect app is not really maintained anymore but it's still a great option for iPhone owners.

The problem is, Mojave left it function as view-only and that renders virtually useless.

So, how do you fix this?

Comment: I have had zero issues with this. I can control my computer as normal from other Macs, or from Remotix on my iPhone, and I didn't get any vnc-related permissions prompts.

Comment: I haven't had any issue either doing it from other macs. Also, as I said, some apps like RealVNC or JumpDesktop have already implemented a fix or at least a workaround. In the case of iTeleport, however, control was just not working (and not displaying a permission request dialog either, which is why I had to find out exactly what process needed to be authorized)

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find an answer online so I took to checking for incoming connections and also in the list of active processes so I could find how to fix it. You need to grant Accesibility privileges to `AppleVNCServer` which you can find under `/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleVNCServer`

Comment: I can't add the path to the Accesibility Controlapane in System Preferences. Because AppleVNCServer.bundle cant activated in this filedialog. How I can add this path to Accessibility Controlpane?

Comment: @kockiren what you do is in a regular finder window, "show package contents", on the bundle, and then navigate to the folder that contains the binary file. Then drag the file from there to the Accessibility open dialog. I had to restart to get the change to apply.

Comment: This works, thx.

Comment: Also `open /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/` in terminal does it nicely in one go.

Comment: found the file, thank you for this. This did not solve my issues connecting with TigerVNC. Am stuck on a 1280x1024 resolution to my MacMini :(

Answer (score 0):

As [VNC explains](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016134372-Remote-access-to-macOS-10-14-Mojave-is-view-only-until-access-is-granted-locally-to-the-vncagent-application), you have to grant access to the vncagent application.

Step by step reproduction:

1. open **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility**
2. Click the **lock** button
3. Click on **+**
4. Navigate to **/Library/vnc/vncagent** and select the Open button

Comment: Yes and no. That is correct for their product obviously, my issue was with apps that connect using Apple's own VNC implementation.

Comment: On 10.14.5 at least, this directory no longer exists and `vncagent` is not found anywhere.